# Comparing all elements with each other inside a nested linked list in C

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list, compare

I have a nested linked list of the form:

```
struct child
{
    char name[15];
    int num;
    struct child *next;
};

struct parent
{
    char name[15];
    struct child *head_child;
    struct parent *next;
};

struct parent *head_parent;
```

and basic comparison function:

```
_Bool compare(int num_1, int num_2)
{
    if(num_1 == num_2)
        return 1;    // Bad; conflicting numbers
    else
        return 0;    // Good!
}
```

For example, a user entered data such that the columns (A, B, C, D, E) represent elements in the parent list, and rows (1-5), represent elements in the child list as illustrated below (pardon my MS Paint skills).

[image: Graphical Example]

**Q: If every working combination of A+B+C+D+E had to be found, where no two numbers can be the same, what algorithms could be used?**

I am planning on storing the resulting successful list in another struct with pointers later for display like such:

```
struct working
{
    char *parent_name;
    char *child_name;
    struct working *next;
};

struct combination
{
    struct working *head;
    struct combination *next;
};
```

If possible, provide a basic example with for/while loops, and if you can show the complexity, that would be a huge bonus :)

Comment: what are the range of the numbers that these nodes can hold? Like `A,B..E` how many parent nodes can be there?

Comment: @coderredoc let's say up to 10 parent/child nodes, and numbers from 1-10 for this example :)

Comment: In general if you want to print every possible cases then you can have a recursive solution but which will take a lot of time for 10x10 case. You can't improve that (when you are printing them). The recursive solution would be something like "from each list you consider one number" and then from the next parent node you select one which will not be something you already selected. And then this goes on recursively for every level.

Comment: You could consider all numbers in one long list (no need to program that explicitly though), loop once over that long list, considering each number in turn as reference. Comparing only the rest of the list to each reference is sufficient, no need to go back for comparing a reference to a number which already has been reference. That works with two loops iteratively, i.e. no recursion needed.

Comment: If you can keep the lists sorted (or sort them before the check) you can do a merge-like comparison.